# Active Admin Sidebar get value from text input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm trying to create a simple sidebar in the :index view of an Active Admin resource that has a two text inputs and button.  I have the button trigger a collection_action when pressed, but I can't figure out how to get the values of both inputs into into the collection_action.  Below is my partial that I render for my sidebar:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/earned_points" class="filter_form" id="new_e" method="get">
  <div class="filter_form_field filter_string search">
    <label class="label" for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" />
  </div>
  <div class="filter_form_field filter_string search">
    <label class="label" for="filename">File Name:</label>
    <input step=any" type="text" id="fileName" placeholder="EarnedPointData" />
    <a href=<%= export_admin_earned_points_path(controller.params) %>>
      <input style="margin-top:15px" type="submit" id="Export" value="Export"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

I seldom do web development so I apologize if this seems like an extremely basic questions.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

UPDATE:

Turns out that my structure was all bad.  Thanks to nistvan for pointing out that I should be able to just pull them out form the params.  From that I realized that I needed to setup my form better.  I ended up use embedded ruby to do this.  Below is my final partial.

```
<%= form_tag export_admin_earned_points_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= label_tag(:email, "Email:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:email, nil, placeholder: 'your@email.com' ) %>
    <%= label_tag(:filename, "File Name:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:filename, nil, placeholder: 'EarnedPointsData') %>
    <%= submit_tag("Export") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach the passed parameters in the controller_action via the params (hash) variable.
You can check how the params looks like if you raise an error in the controller action:

```
raise params.inspect
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I attempted this, but they weren't in the params.  I ended up realizing that my structure was all wrong.  I'm going to update my question to show what I did to allow me to pull the params out.  Thanks.